# Comparing Characters to Strings

Tags: c

I'm to write a code in C to let the user enter the first and last characters of the word `"fantastic"`. If he is correct for the two answers it should print `"Well done"`, if he gets one wrong then it should print `"one of your answers is incorrect"` if he gets both incorrect i tell him to try again later.

Below is the code I tried which doesn't allow me to enter the second character and also gets the answer wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char word[] = "fantastic";
    char in1, in2;
    printf("Please enter the first letter of the word \'fantastic\': ");
    scanf("%c", &in1);
    printf("\nPlease enter the last letter of the word \'fantastic\': ");
    scanf("%c", &in2);
    if (in1 == word[0], in2 == word[8]) {
        printf("\nWell Done!\n");
    }
    else if (in1 == word[0], in2 != word[8], in1 != word[0], in2 == word[8]) {
        printf("\nOne of your answers is incorrect!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nTry again next time!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to use logical operators like `&&` (and) or `||` (or) instead of the comma operator in the conditions of your `if`-statements.

Comment: What would be the acted upon condition in `if (in1 == word[0], in2 == word[8])`? `in2 == word[8]` only?

Comment: @Swordfish Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: i'm a total beginner so i was just trying my hands on it

Comment: @Swordfish thanks, but I would be much happier if I get a sample code of it

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot write code at random trying to guess the syntax until it compiles. the commas aren't doing what you expect

Comment: I'm tempted to close as dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do

Comment: It isn't necessary to define this: `char word[] = "fantastic";`. Instead of `word[0]` and `word[8]` you can use `'f'` and `'c'`.

Comment: @Swordfish Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: worse than a dupe: a "fix my code" question. or composite duplicate. Since the scanf issue is also a well known dupe

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha, agreed.

Comment: but I've always answered stuff like this in the C section when I was "younger". So...

Answer (score 3):

> code I tried which doesn't allow me to enter the second character

After

```
scanf("%c", &in1);
```

The newline (`'\n'`) you entered after the character is still in the input buffer and will get consumed by

```
scanf("%c", &in2);
```

so you have no opportunity to enter another one. You can change both to

```
scanf(" %c" // ...
//     ^
```

to skip leading whitespace.

> also gets the answer wrong

The next problems are with your `if`-statements: If you use the comma-operator between the tests for equality, the result for the whole expression will only be the rightmost subexpression:

```
in1 == word[0], in2 == word[8]
```

evaluates to `in2 == word[8]`. The part before the comma has no effect on it.

When you have two boolean expressions like tests for equality you have to link them with a logical *and* (`&&`) to make the whole expression true when both sides of `&&` are true:

```
in1 == word[0] && in2 == word[8]
```

Similarly you should use a logical *or* (`||`) if you want the whole expression be true when at least one side of `||` is true.

So your code should look like that:

```
if (in1 == word[0] && in2 == word[8]) {
    printf("\nWell Done!\n");
}
else if (in1 == word[0] && in2 != word[8] || in1 != word[0] && in2 == word[8]) {
    printf("\nOne of your answers is incorrect!\n");
}
else {
    printf("\nTry again next time!\n");
}
```

As suggested by [Fiddling Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2993960/fiddling-bits) you don't have to define an array for the word if you have no other use for it other than checking for two letters:

```
char const first = 'f';
char const last  = 'c';

if (in1 == first && in2 == last) {
    printf("\nWell Done!\n");
}
else if (in1 == first && in2 != last || in1 != first && in2 == last) {
    printf("\nOne of your answers is incorrect!\n");
}
else printf("\nTry again next time!\n");
```

Less comparisons and logic is needed if you swap the order:

```
if (in1 == first && in2 == last) {  // both correct
    printf("\nWell Done!\n");
}
else if (in1 != first && in2 != last) {  // both wrong
    printf("\nTry again next time!\n");
}
else printf("\nOne of your answers is incorrect!\n");
```

Comment: thanks so much, I've tried all your comments and I think its working...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggestions and it's working out
Thanks so much.....
Below is the final code which is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char word[] = "fantastic";
char in1, in2;
printf("Please enter the first letter of the word \'fantastic\':");
scanf(" %c", &in1);
printf("Please enter the last letter of the word \'fantastic\':");
scanf(" %c", &in2);
if (in1 == word[0] && in2 == word[8]) {
printf("\nWell Done!\n");
}
else if (in1 == word[0] && in2 != word[8] || in1 != word[0] && in2 == word[8]) {
printf("\nOne of your answers is incorrect!\n");
}
else {
printf("\nTry again next time!\n");
}
return 0;
}
```